# How well will AWS Lambda handle 10,000 S3 triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We're at the beginning stages of writing a AWS Lambda to copy massive amounts of s3 files within S3.

This Lambda will be triggered from S3.

Any advice about what the max triggers are that Lambda can handle at one time? for example, if we dump 10,000 trigger files in the S3 trigger folder, will Lambda handle this pretty well or will it throttle itself back enough to slow the whole thing down? Would there be a better recommended number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the triggers to Lambda (Works with SNS) are not scalable with high number of concurrent objects copied. There are other limits that takes this to a different issue. Lambda concurrency limits, Lambda Cold Start.

One way we got the triggers to work is to send it to SNS and forward it to lambda from there. It will be queued and delivered by SNS. You will see certain latency with the roundtrip to SNS.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

On the other hand, if you still want to retain the trigger without worrying about time. It worked fine with a 500milliseconds between each successful copy. So that it will not fire all trigger at once.

This was our testing first and worked successfully but took longer time. With SNS no throttling required.

Comment: Thank you. So what sort of throughput were you seeing with your use of SNS? How many completed transactions per second or minute?

Comment: AWS SNS topic has 'Maximum receive rate'. It tells SNS how to throttle lambda at a given point of time. We set it to 25, that worked enough for us. Means at point of time there will be only 25 topics delivered, rest of them will be in queue. More on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/DeliveryPolicies.html .

Comment: Interesting, so one could make two SNS topics and two duplicate Lambdas (different name,) subscribed to each topic. Then have a master Lambda that deals events evenly between both topics to cut the time in half/double throughput.

Comment: You will hit the lambda concurrency limit. If you want to double the throughput just set the Max receive rate to 50, that will increase the number of concurrent lambda. You also need to make sure the dependencies of the lambda are also scalable to this limit.

Comment: But the concurrency limit is hit within one individual lambda, I may well hit that,  but what I'm I'm saying is that if you have two separate worker lambdas (that do the same thing) working for you you'll get double the work, whether you hit the concurrency limits of each or not.

Comment: Concurrent limits is for the account, you can optionally restrict to a specific lambda. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html